# MSSQL - Retrieve ID if condition for all rows of this ID is valid

Tags: sql-server, select

Just a quick question. I have table like this:

```
╔══════╦═════════════╗
║ id   ║     date    ║
╠══════╬═════════════╣
║   90 ║  2100-01-01 ║
║   90 ║  2100-01-01 ║
║   91 ║  2100-01-01 ║
║   91 ║  null       ║
║   92 ║  2100-01-01 ║
║   92 ║  2100-01-01 ║
║   92 ║  null       ║
║   93 ║  2100-01-01 ║
╚══════╩═════════════╝
```

I want to write a query that will retrieve only those IDs that have a date higher than current date in ALL of its rows. I that case:

```
╔════╗
║ id ║
╠════╣
║ 90 ║
║ 93 ║
╚════╝
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to google first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT distinct id 
FROM   table1 
WHERE  id NOT IN (SELECT id 
                  FROM   table1 
                  WHERE  isnull(date,'') < Getdate())
```

Take a look at a working example on <kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7c22d/5)</kbd>

Comment: I edited a little bit my question just after you replied, but your answer is great. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, if you want any more changes, just post a comment :-)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to find all ID's where all dates are in the future? I would use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT distinct(id) 
FROM   table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM table1 t2
  WHERE t2.id = t1.id
  AND ISNULL(t2.date, GETDATE()) <= GetDate()
)
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/63d6c/1/0)</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

The idea is, to create a subquery which returns those same ids, where the minimum date (within the same ids) is bigger than the current date. I like to use the outer SQL too, because as soon as you want to add columns to the output, you have to create it anyway if you do not want to retouch the group by.

```
SELECT id 
FROM tab
WHERE id in
  (SELECT id
  FROM tab
  GROUP BY id
  HAVING MIN(IFNULL(date, GETDATE())) > GETDATE())
GROUP BY id
```